# Books on command interfaces / interactive visualizations

Tags: visualization, interactive

Note: marked as community wiki.

Note: before voting to close "not real question" -- the question is: What are the common interactive visualization design patterns?

Exposition:

I have this gigantic real time simulation. I'm working on interactive visualization tools to monitor the simulation. I'm familiar with OpenGL but not used to writing HCI / visualization type code. So I'm curious: what books/articles should I be reading?

I'm looking for the "The C Programming Language / SICP / Design Patterns" type of equivament resource for writing *interactive* visualizations. "Interactive" is important -- I don't want to just generate pretty pictures; I want to generate pretty pictures and be able to interact & probe the visualization.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I can't recommend any books, but something you may be interested in that I have used is the RealityGrid steering framework:
http://www.rcs.manchester.ac.uk/research/realitygrid
http://code.google.com/p/computational-steering/
We use this for real time visualization of fluid dynamic simulations.